# How to use similar UI materializecss framework to android design?

Tags: android, material-design, materialize

Is there a way to use a similar Framework as [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) to Design Android Apps?
Or apply CSS to my design in an Android App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you must target to 5.0 and use elements like "toolbar", "palette", between others.

On github you have: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Material.md with dozens of material design elements, widgets, etc and most of them from Android 2.3+. Those are really easy to use and most of them only need a gradler declaration.

Hope that helps you.